# What does "coming in hot" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I've heard it in the "Demolition ranch" and don't have a clue what it means.
https://youtu.be/79V2iJ6L7lE?t=755 12:35

Comment: He says "[this bullet is] coming in hot" to the target dummy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Coming in hot" is an idiom meaning that something/someone is approaching with great speed. I hear this mostly in either athletics, to refer to competitors who are catching up, but here it just means that the bullet is approaching quickly toward the dummy.

Comment: In military contexts "coming in hot" can mean "approaching ready to fire/attack" but that does not seem to be what is intended here.